# My code moves when I readjust the size of the window

Tags: html, css, web

My code moves when I readjust the size of the browser window. What are some ways I can stop it from moving?

Below is an example of one of the pages I have made for my website.Please help!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My work! </title>
        <style>

            body{
                background-image: url(back.jpg);
                background-size: 900px 1100px;
                background-attachment: fixed;
            }

            #Title {
                color: white;
                font-size: 100px;
                position: relative;
                top: 70px;
                left: 100px;
                width: 500px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: rgb(139,69,41);
                text-align: center;
            }

            .homemenu {
                background-color: rgb(139,69,41);
                width: 60px;
                height: 100px;
                position: absolute; 
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
                color: white;
                padding: 7px 10px 18px;
                text-align: center;
                top: 356px;
            }

            .homemenu:hover{
                top: 326px;
            }

            p{
                position: relative;
                left: 10px;
                margin-top: 40px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            #Linkbox{
                position: relative;
                left: 50px;
                top: 0px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0px 180px 100px 50px;
                background-color: rgb(255,210,120);
                color: rgb(139,69,41);
            }

            ul{
                margin-left: 60px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #Logo{
                color: white;
                font-size: 100px;
                position: relative;
                top: 20px;
                left: 200px;
                width: 1500px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: rgb(139,69,41);
                text-align: center;
            }

            .pleb{
                position: relative;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                top: 10px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id ="Logo"> <img src = "pleb.jpg" class = "pleb"/><span> Miguel's Final Project </span> <img src = "pleb.jpg" class = "pleb"/></div>           
        <div class = "homemenu" style = "left: 1200px;"> <a href= "final project miguel home.html"> Home </a></div>
        <div class = "homemenu" style = "left: 1300px;"> <a href= "final project miguel about.html"> About </a></div>
        <div class = "homemenu" style = "left: 1400px;"> <a href= "final project miguel pic gal.html"> Picture Gallery </a></div>
        <div class = "homemenu" style = "left: 1500px;"> <a href= "final project miguel video.html"> My Favourite Video! </a></div>
        <div class = "homemenu" style = "left: 1600px;"> <a href= "final project miguel mywork.html"> My Work. </a> </div>
        <h1 id = "Title"> My Work! </h1>

        <div id = "Linkbox">
            <p id = "worktalk">
                The following are examples of some of the work I've done over this first semester. It includes assignments, </br>
                labs, in class exercises and just me messing around with skills learnt in lesson. Choose one and take a look for yourself!
            </p>
            </br></br></br>
            <ul> <label> My work list: </label></br></br>
                <a href = "Assignment3/Storytime linkto.html" title = "Story lab"> Make a Story! </a></br></br></br>
                <a href = "Week 1 HW/RadSitemainproject.html" title = "First website!"> Rad Site! </a></br></br></br>
                <a href = "Calculator/Cal main project miguel.html" title = "Trying out functions"> Calculator </a></br></br></br>
                <a href = "Assignment 1/main project rainbow.html" title = "Single rainbows, not double...."> Rainbow Website </a></br></br></br>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle or code snippet would be wonderful. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: What do you mean by code snippet? Is the code I posted not visible? D:

Comment: A code snippet allows people who are looking at your question to actually run your code without having to setup a test experiment on their local machine; thus saving a lot of unnecessary time. A jsfiddle allows more options for doing a code snippet. Just go to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine what you mean by "my code moves", but you have one detail in there that certainly causes movement of at least one part:

```
.homemenu {
…
top: 356px; 
}
.homemenu:hover {
 top: 326px; 
}
```

This will cause *all* your menu entries to be moved up by 30px when you hover over any of them. Also, they are absolutely positioned which is not a good idea...